# Issue after nesting async.eachOfSeries

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I was using nested for loops to get a thing done. I figured out that the HTTP call and the database query are asynchronous and eventually gives undesired output. So I used async.eachOfSeries. The execution gets stopped just after it enters the inner most async.eachOfSeries in the first iteration itself. I suppose I have made some error is structuring the code and in returning the callbacks. I need to know basically two things from you:

1. What is stopping the execution of the code in the first iteration itself?
2. Will this approach solve the asynchronicity issue? Or is there any better approach to solve it?

Your help would be appreciated.

```
    async.eachOfSeries(res, function (value, camp, callback) {
        let _id = res[camp]._id;
        let arr = res[camp].campaignID;
        async.eachOfSeries(arr, function (value1, i, callback) {
            let users = arr[i].users;
            let id = arr[i].id;
            let loop = Math.ceil(users / 1000);
            let limit = 0,
                offset = 0;
            for (let j = 0; j < loop; j++) {
                if (users > 1000) {
                    limit = 1000;
                    users -= limit;
                } else {
                    limit = users;
                }
                console.log(limit + " limit " + offset + " offset");
                var start = Date.now();
                while (Date.now() < start + 100) {}
                const request = mailjet
                    .get("messagesentstatistics")
                    .request({
                        "CampaignID": id,
                        "AllMessages": true,
                        "Limit": limit,
                        "Offset": offset
                    })
                request
                    .then((result) => {
                        let data = result.body.Data;
                        var loop = 0;
                        async.eachOfSeries(data, function (value2, val, callback) {
                            console.log("ayyuuuuu");
                            let jsonObj = data[val];
                            let email = jsonObj.ToEmail;
                            jsonObj['retailer'] = res[camp].retailer;
                            jsonObj['summary'] = 'f';
                            let tempObj = {};
                            tempObj[id] = jsonObj;
                            let options = {
                                new: true
                            };
                            let campId = id;
                            User.addCampaignResponse(email, campId, tempObj, options, function (err, results) {
                                if (err) {
                                    throw err;
                                } else {
                                    Campaign.updateResponse(_id, function (err, results2) {
                                        if (err)
                                            throw err;
                                    }) // console.log(results);
                                }
                            })
                        }, function (err) {
                            callback();
                        })
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                offset += limit;
            }
        }, function (err) {
            callback();
        })
    }, function (err) {
        callback(undefined, "doneeeeee");
    })
```

Comment: Please use functions, it would be way easier to read, and then to correct. Even when you are developing to `try` someting, it's never bad to construct properly a code.

Comment: Nice little [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) you got yourself there :)

Comment: Any solutions? @James